# rails application not sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Developerment.rb

```
myapp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false

  #config.whiny_nils = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  #config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # config.log_level = :error
end

#log ActiveRecord
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) if defined? Rails::Console
```

I am seeing the in the log file the message "Sent mail to name1.name2@domain.com".
I have played with this line

```
#config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

by uncommenting this and gave all these options `:smtp, :sendmail or :test,` but none seems to work.

Comment: have you configured your server settings to send e-mails? you can do that via ActionMailer::Base check this out: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

Comment: @Mavis, I have this one configured in my appln,   ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(SMInterceptor)

Comment: are you trying to send e-mails using a smtp or sendmail server?

Comment: @Mavis, I am using smtp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using SMTP to send e-mails, then make sure you include the server configuration in your config/environments/$RAILS_ENV.rb file. here is an example:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            '<username>',
  password:             '<password>',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

Comment: Also you may include: config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' } - by it addining above, the above block. production.rb would then reflect the actual hostname

Comment: @user3677652 When you get the error in production, add the line with the host name with the production name, and then you may find my comment more useful to the post